# Item "None" of "Optional[str]" has no attribute "split" [union-attr]

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a function that processes an AWS Lambda context, looking for a query string parameter.

The return value for the function is always a Tuple that contains the error code and the returned value. In case of success, it returns `(None, the_value_of_the_query_string)`. In case of failure, it returns `(Exception, None)`.

The code is written to behave similarly to what is very commonly seen in the Go world.

Here is the line triggering the warning:

```py
file_name = file_path.split("/")[-1]
```

And below is the code that takes you through everything.

```py
class QSException(Exception):
    pass


def get_query_string(
    event: Dict, query_string: str
) -> Union[Tuple[QSException, None], Tuple[None, str]]:
    error = QSException()
    #* [...snip...]
    if not query_string in event["queryStringParameters"]:
        return (error, None)
    return (None, event["queryStringParameters"][query_string])


def get_file(event: Dict, context: Dict) -> Dict:
    err, file_path = get_query_string(event, "file")
    if err is not None:
        message = {"message": "No file specified."}
        return {"statusCode": 403, "body": json.dumps(message)}

    # from here on I'm on the happy path
    file_name = file_path.split("/")[-1]

    #* [...snip...]
    return {
        #* [...bogus dict...]
    }
```

If you follow the code, I treat the exceptions first and return 403 on the unhappy path. That is, once I've processed all exceptions I know for a fact that the error code was `None` and my result was a `str`. So I would expect that doing a `.split("/")` would work (which it does) and not trigger a typing warning.

Instead, I'm getting `Item "None" of "Optional[str]" has no attribute "split" [union-attr]`.

So the question is how should typing look for this code so that I don't get this typing warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is annotated correctly.
However when you unpack the tuple `err, file_path = get_...` the connection between those two variables is lost.
A static code analyzer (mypy, pyright, ...) will now assume that `err` is an `Optional[QSException]` and `file_path` is an `Optional[str]`. And when you check for the type of the first variable, it doesn't have any effect on the second variable type.

If you really want to keep that idiom, returning a tuple `(exception, value)`, then just help the static code analyzers with asserts.
It's manual work (and therefore error prone), but I guess the tools are not clever enough to figure out the correct type in such a case.

```py
err, file_path = get_query_string(event, "file")
if err:
    return ...

assert isinstance(file_path, str)
# now static code analyzers know the correct type
```

However Python is not the same language as Go, and has completely different idioms.
Returning such a tuple is an antipattern in Python. Python, unlike Go, has real exceptions. So use them.

```py
def get_query_string(event: Dict, query_string: str) -> str:
    if not query_string in event["queryStringParameters"]:
        raise QSException()
    return event["queryStringParameters"][query_string]


def get_file(event: Dict, context: Dict) -> Dict:
    try:
        file_path = get_query_string(event, "file")
    except QSException:
        message = {"message": "No file specified."}
        return {"statusCode": 403, "body": json.dumps(message)}

    file_name = file_path.split("/")[-1]
```

Or alternatively just return an `Optional[str]` in case you don't wanna raise an exception, or a `Union[QSE, str]`.