# error: Item "None" of "Optional[str]" has no attribute "split" [union-attr] MyPy Error

Tags: python, mypy, pep8

```
# If word count threshold is set, calculate the total word count
            if self.word_count_threshold:
                word_count += len(documents[doc_idx].content.split())
```

For this code snippet mypy gives an error. Is there an alternative to using .split() here so mypy does not give this error? Is there an PEP8 convention or type casting that has to be done to resolve this?

Comment: It’s pointing out that `documents[doc_idx].content` *may be `None`* according to its typing, in which case this code would raise an error. Test whether the value is not `None` before trying to call `split` on it.

Comment: I tested it and found that documents[doc_idx].content is None when initialized but does not remain none in subsequent steps. What should be the way to tackle this?

Comment: Again: `if documents[doc_idx].content is not None: ...`

Comment: I do get that it is None at initializing then what should be the appropriate type hints to resolve this error?

Comment: mypy still complains even if you add the guard test?

Comment: Yes it still gives the error.

Comment: It shouldn't: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=3abeb5a0dde2f307e03424addeab6040

Answer (score 1):

mypy is not a very smart tool. I'm experiencing similar issues with the tool. I'm almost thinking I remove this from my CI pipeline. Nonetheless, this might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75371117/16314572

Personally, though, and while it might beat the entire purpose of mypy, I tend to just ignore unnecessary errors that mypy throws. In my case, I know for a fact, the code is doing exactly what it's supposed to do and will not error so ignoring type checking for that line makes sense. If you want to do that, in the line that's throwing an error do this:

`...code  # type: ignore`